# what salt is used for in sorcery gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, sorcery

How exactly does sorcery authenticates user? What is salt and how to change sorcery default column names?

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email", null: false
  t.string   "crypted_password"
  t.string   "salt"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Comment: That's... 3 completely unrelated questions.

Answer (score 1):

In standard cryptography, a '**salt**' is used to ensure that password hashes are more secure. In Sorcery it does this by joining a random string to the end of the password and remembering that string in the salt field.

So when encrypting a new password, the pseudocode is:

```
hashing_algorithm('passed in password' + salt) => crypted_password
```

and when authenticating, the comparison is (Sorcery actually overrides 'matches?'):

```
crypted_password == hashing_algorithm('passed in password' + salt)
```

That way, even if the same password is used by multiple users, it's not obvious from the data as a different hash will be generated every time.